# Intellij no me reconoce los nombres de las anotaciones JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, intellij-idea

Estoy tengiendo un problema MUY raro. hasta hace un dia nomas, al anotar 
simplemente:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "productos")
public class Producto implements Serializable {
```

no tenia problemas pero ahora me aparece asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo marcado me dice: cannont resolve table 'productos'

No tiene sentido, el proyecto compila, me crea la tabla todo!!
pero me sigue marcando eso
y lo peor es que ahora me lo marca en cada proyecto que tengo, incluso cuando estos no lo marcaban anteriormente!

Comment: Intenta conectar la base de datos en Intellij `View -> Tool Windows -> Database` de esta forma te reconocerá las tablas de la base de datos.

Comment: Intentaste hacer un clean install o restablecer el cache de Intellij?